# sqlite3 and node-js returns undefined

Tags: javascript, sqlite

I'm trying to pass value from **sqlite3** function with **Node.js** but I'm getting always `undefined`.

Here is my code:

```
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var db = new sqlite3.Database('./rolety.db');
var row;

db.get("SELECT open_hour, open_minut FROM autorun_open", function(err, row) {
    console.log(row.open_hour);
    console.log(row.open_minut);
    row = row.open_hour;
});

console.log("R:" + row);
```

As far, as I can see, its run asynchronously, cause I obtain something like that:

```
Row: undefined
6
45
```

Last line of my code is running before sql result. What should I do, to obtain correct value from sql?

Answer (score 4):

You need to add a callback function like this:

```
db.get("SELECT open_hour, open_minut FROM autorun_open", function(err, row) {
    console.log(row.open_hour);
    console.log(row.open_minut);
    row = row.open_hour;
    callback(row);
});

function callback(row) {
    console.log("R:" + row);
}
```

The trick is, that the callback function gets called **after** the get is successful or not. In the next step you should think about error handling if the get fails.